# Make VS2017 launch chrome with profile with F5

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2017

When I run my project from Visual Studio 2017 it launches Chrome, but it's a clean slate version of chrome. I have noticed it do that with other projects too so I think it is a setting in VS2017

I want it to load into my regular chrome profile with the extensions I have installed etc.

I have tried tinkering with browse with function and setting it there, but I just cant get it to work..
I haven't normally had to set a profile here, so not sure what the issue is

Also when the chrome instance loads, If i try and sign into that instance I get
:

> Couldn't sign you in This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
> Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported
> browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to disable "Script Debugging" under "IIS Express", now it's all fine again, must have enabled it by accident